# Find the function and domain for $ (f\circ f)$ when $ f(x) = x+ \frac {1} {x} \ $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the function and domain for $ (f\circ f)$

My answer is $ \frac {x^4+3x^2+1x} {(x^2+1)(x)}?$

However, the program I am using states I am wrong. What have I done incorrectly?

Comment: Why do you have an $x$ in the numerator?  It should be a $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ (f\circ f)=x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{x^2+1}{x}+\frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^4+x^2+x^2+1+x^2}{x(x^2+1)}=\frac{x^4+3x^2+1}{x(x^2+1)}$$

The domain is right, it's $\ x≠0$, but in the numerator you have 1 and not $\ 1x$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = x + \frac 1x = \frac {x^2+1}{x}$$

$$f(f(x)) = \frac{x^2 + 1}{x} + \frac{1}{\frac{x^2+1}x} = \frac{x^2+1}{x} + \frac{x}{x^2+1} = \frac{(x^2+1)^2 + x^2}{x(x^2+1)} = \frac{x^4 + 3x^2 + 1}{x(x^2 + 1)}$$

Domain: All $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $x\neq 0.$ (The denominator is undefined only when $x = 0.)$ $$(-\infty, 0)\cup (0, +\infty)$$

Note that $x^2 + 1 \gt 0\;\; \forall x \in \mathbb R$.